# Dojo onchange and IE8 Compatibility Issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dojo, spring-roo

with my great pleasure I've just inherited a web app project made with Spring Roo (version 1.3.1) and I am struggling with the tedious task of make it compatible across multiple browsers.

More specifically I am trying to make the following few JS lines work under IE8:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
   dojo.addOnLoad(function() {  
   dojo.connect(dijit.byId("conversionRateTarget_id"), "onchange", function(){

   var field = dijit.byId("_conversionRateTarget_id");
   var field2 = dijit.byId("_volumeTarget_id");
   var field3 = dijit.byId("_specTarget_id");

   field3.set('value', Math.floor(field2.getValue()*(field.getValue()/100)));
   });
   });
</SCRIPT>
```

Every time a value changes in a specific input box, a new value for a second field is calculated. It's really basic.

The function perfectly works under Firefox, Chrome and IE9-11, but not using IE8 (native or in compatibility mode).

I wouldn't call myself a JS expert and it's the first time I am working with a Dojo library, but even with extensive search I wasn't able to find the reason behind this "mulfunctioning" in IE8.

The Dojo version used is 1.5. The library is packed in spring-js-resources-2.2.1-RELEASE.jar

Did someone stumble upon a similar issue?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: is there any error in the F12 tool ? if use IE11 with IE8 mode forced, the F12 tool may give you more details.

Comment: Hi ben, thanks for the hint. Unfortunately no error at all, I forgot to mention this. Neither in IE8 forced mode, nor natively. It executes dojo.addOnLoad but the following dojo.connect isn't perfomed.

Comment: `dijit.byId("conversionRateTarget_id")` returns a widget and what you need is a `domNode` I guess. Try either `dojo.byId` or `dijit.byId("conversionRateTarget_id").domNode`

Comment: Unfortunately same behaviour as before. No errors or warnings showed :(

Comment: Can you setup a jsfidle or a snippet ?

Comment: I'll do it ASAP thanks. In the meantime I discovered that the conversionRateTarget element get widgetted to a    dijit.form.ValidationTextBox    type. I remember something about onchange events not working properly on a form under IE8... am I wrong?